# LINQ create new object and order by property

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, sql-order-by

with this query I create a new object:

```
                var allData = from op in _opg
                          join tp in _tpg on op.DataGiorno equals tp.DataGiorno
                          join ts in _tsg on op.DataGiorno equals ts.DataGiorno
                          select new {op, tp, ts};
```

the main source, **"_opg"** is a List>. Basically as **"op"** is a DateTime type, I would order this new object by **"op"** in ascending way.
Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just add an `orderby` clause in the LINQ query:

```
var allData = from op in _opg
              join tp in _tpg on op.DataGiorno equals tp.DataGiorno
              join ts in _tsg on op.DataGiorno equals ts.DataGiorno
              orderby op ascending
              select new {op, tp, ts}
```

This requires the type of op to implement `IComparable<[type of op]>`.